# How to publish/update Infopath form 2013 of SharePoint List?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, infopath

I had one custom list in SharePoint 2013. Infopath form has been created for this list and published.

Note: **casetype is a lookup column**

When I'm trying to update the InfoPath form and while publishing it throws below error.

```
Server was unable to process request ---> A duplicate field name "casetype" was found
```

I have only one option left to delete and recreate it but the list has 500 records. So I can't do this. Has any one facing this issue.

[image]